# Rails: Date format in forms and database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, date-format

I have a form which has a datepicker that shows a date with the format:

```
'%m/%d/%Y'
```

The problem is when I submit the form, this format is not a valid date, so it is not sent to the database on the INSERT INTO/UPDATE.

Nevertheless, it works if I submit a date with this format:

```
'%Y-%d-%m'
```

I have seen that I can do something like this before saving the object to the database:

```
my_object.due_date = params[:content_date].to_date.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

But as I have more than one date field and more than one model with date fields, I would like to avoid doing an **strftime()** everywhere.

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Which date picker? Some can display in one format but send to the server in a different format. IMO your best bet is to use ISO8601 (`YYYY-MM-DD`) except at the edges.

Comment: I am using the bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Have you checked its documentation for what options it supports?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `gem 'momentjs-rails'`, because of the datetime picker.

model

```
#deadline is saved in the db
#this is the getter-setter for deadline_string
def deadline_string
  deadline.to_datetime.iso8601
end

def deadline_string=(deadline_str)
  self.deadline = deadline_str
end
```

forms

```
#new form
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :deadline %>
  <%= f.text_field :deadline, class: "form-control new-task-deadline" %>
</div>

#edit form
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :deadline %>
  <%= f.text_field :deadline_string, class: "form-control edit-task-deadline" %>
</div>
```

js when saving to db

```
$('.new-task-submit').on('click', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var localMoment = moment($('.new-task-deadline').val());
  $('.new-task-deadline').val(localMoment.toISOString());
  $('#newtask').submit();
});

$(document).on('click', '.edit-task-submit', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var deadlineField = $('.edit-task-deadline');
  var localMoment = moment(deadlineField.val());
  var railsDate = localMoment.toISOString();
  deadlineField.val(railsDate);
  $(".task-update-form").submit();
});
```

js to show nice data on get request

```
//setting time and datetimepicker when opening edit task modal
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#update-task-modal', function (e) {
  var deadlineField =  $('.edit-task-deadline');
  var deadlineValue = deadlineField.attr('value');
  var momentDeadline = moment(deadlineValue).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
  deadlineField.val(momentDeadline);
  deadlineField.datetimepicker({
    sideBySide: true,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A',
    stepping: 15,
    widgetPositioning: { vertical: 'bottom' }
  });
});
```